# Can't run .NET 7.0.14 app on Azure App Service

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am creating a BitBucket pipeline to build an existing .NET application which runs fine on my development machine and currently builds and runs fine on Azure App Service. However, the build pipeline uses the latest Docker image which builds the app for .NET 7.0.14 - however it fails to run on Azure App Service which only has 7.0.13 installed.

How can I run the app on Azure? Ideally I want to avoid just building for 7.0.13 specifically because I would have to change my dev machine .NET version, etc.

I have tried setting the target framework in global.json, but this caused issues on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, specify the base image with matching azure env version for example:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.13 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy project and restore
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# build
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0.13
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "YourServiceApp.dll"]
```

Comment: I'm not using Docker for deployments. I solved my problem by using a self-contained build of the .NET app.